# Tensorboard projector animated transition between multiple datasets

Tags: tensorboard, projector

I would like to use the stand-alone tensorboard projector and have multiple datasets (same data points, different times).
I want the projector to load multiple datasets, apply PCA and then animate the points in time through the "checkpoints". (changing the point coordinates in the 2D/3D space in an animated fashion)

Where can I start to dig in the projector code in order to load multiple datasets and change the rendered points coordinates after initial render?

Answer (score 0):

With still nearly zero experience with Tensorboard, I recently searched for a similar feature.

Loading multiple datasets in TensorboardX is no problem by calling [add_embedding](https://tensorboardx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tensorboard.html#tensorboardX.SummaryWriter.add_embedding) multiple times with different global_step parameter. It seems that for transitions there is no build-in solution.

One alternative I suggest is [hypertools](https://hypertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It supports multiple dimension reduction methods, as well as animations.

I would appreciate any update on this topic as I am still searching for alternatives.